# Visual studio code not showing output, java programming

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, output

I'm learning to code Java...
I just installed the Java runtime environment and Visual Studio Code, and wrote this:

```
public class IterationDemo

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println('x');
    }
}
```

However, I don't see any output, both under output or terminal. Only kind of a rectangle (▯) under terminal.
I've tried to find a solution googling, stack and so on but no answer yet...
what can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Please post what you see in terminal

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/GcFctGMWUhDD.png

Answer (score 0):

OK; got solved on its own - I ended up clearing the cache and then the output came :)
Thanks myself!